# Managing data access in a simple WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, datatable, sqlconnection

I have a simple WinForms data entry app that uses SQLite. It will always be a single-user app and always with a local database. I have multiple tabs, with UserControls serving as content for the tabs. Each time a tab is selected, an appropriate UserControl is initialized, and the old one is removed (using TabPage.Controls.Remove).

Each UserControl initializes a generic DataAccess object, which wraps all the database stuff and can be reused with any tab content. The issue is that I have an open SQLiteConnection for the duration of the life of the tab (UserControl). I've read elsewhere that it's not a good practice. I don't want to overkill on the design with elaborate data layers and business object layers, partly because I don't know how to do it, and partly because I don't think it's necessary for this app.

I'm basically keeping the same connection, adapter, DataTable, SqlCommand, etc objects in memory and just reusing them with different sql query parameters, and to get that cached data with other methods (like RowCount). I had a problem with LoadData method as it was not clearing out previous query results from DataTable, so I'm doing it manually in the beginning.

I tried figuring out a way to use "using" with SQLiteConnection and other objects, but then I'd have to redo the whole DataLoad stuff or similar for simple things like RowCount. So I'm just looking for suggestions and comments on this approach with data access.

Below is my DataAccess class.

```
public class DataAccess
{
    private SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(Global.DbConnectionString);
    private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    private SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
    private SQLiteCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder();
    private SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
    private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();


    public DataAccess()
    {
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        commandBuilder.DataAdapter = dataAdapter;
        bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
    }

    ~DataAccess()
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }

    public BindingSource BindingSource
    {
        get { return bindingSource; }
    }


    ///*
    public void LoadData(string sql, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            dataTable.Clear();
            command.Connection = connection;

            // Ignore sql parameter if we already have CommandText. This assumes sql never changes per instance
            if (command.CommandText == null)
                command.CommandText = sql;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> parameter in parameters)
            {
                if (command.Parameters.Contains(parameter.Key))
                    command.Parameters[parameter.Key].Value = parameter.Value;
                else
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(parameter.Key));
                    command.Parameters[parameter.Key].Value = parameter.Value;
                }
            }
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Problem, need to display what's wrong later");
        }

    }//*/

    public int RowCount()
    {
        return dataTable.Rows.Count;
    }

    public string GetFieldValue(int row_index, string column_name)
    {
        return dataTable.Rows[row_index][column_name].ToString();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    }

    public void NewRow(Dictionary<string, string> fields)
    {
       DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> field in fields)
            dataRow[field.Key] = field.Value;

        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: With this design, are you able to unit test your application?

Comment: No, unit testing is not even considered yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it nicely, you should create a data access layer that would expose methods to fetch the data and modify it. This layer would open a connection whenever it's necessary and then close it. You could add a caching layer on top of it. And your GUI would only use the data objects from the lower layers.

It's not a small rewrite, so if your current solution works, and you don't want to put much effort into it, then just leave it like this, it's not that bad. If it's a simple program, then this simple solution is just fine.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any examples of such apps that I can look at?